# Type cast from unsigned const char * to char const *

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I want to convert `unsigned const char *` to `char const *` for passing into `strcpy` function

Please suggest some method

Comment: Now getting error " illegal cast"

Comment: "Now getting error" -- what do you mean by "now"? What have you done -- where is your code? Could you add all this to the question (not in comments)?

Answer (score 7):

```
(const char *) my_signed_char
```

In C++ there are more idiomatic ways to cast this, but since you are using strcpy you are not programming idiomatic C++ it seems.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me; is it what you had in mind?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   const char foo[] = "foo";
   unsigned const char * x = (unsigned const char *) foo;

   char bar[20];
   strcpy(bar, (const char *)x);

   printf("bar=[%s]\n", bar);
   return 0;
}
```

Note that if you are instead trying to pass the (unsigned const char *) pointer into strcpy's first argument, then you are probably trying to do something you shouldn't (and the compiler is right to flag it as an error); because strcpy() will write into the memory pointed to by its first argument, and a const pointer is a pointer whose data should not be written to.

Answer (score 1):

In ANSI C I believe it should just work e.g.:

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  const char *s="test";

  unsigned const char *d = s;
  char dest[1000];

  strcpy(dest,d);
}
```

You could try adding a cast:

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  const char *s="test";

  unsigned const char *d = s;
  char dest[1000];

  strcpy(dest,(const char *) d);
}
```